# Scrolling QTableWidget smoothly

Tags: qt, scroll, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget with custom Widgets. These widgets are big and fill almost the whole scroll area in height, so that only one row is visible.

I can scroll with the mouse wheel or by dragging the scroll bar, but the row always jumps.

Is there a way to configure the QTableWidget to smoothly scroll, without jumping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
view->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel)
```

From Qt documentation:

> enum  ScrollMode { ScrollPerItem, ScrollPerPixel }
>
> verticalScrollMode : ScrollMode
>
> This property holds how the view scrolls its contents in the vertical
>   direction.
>
> This property controls how the view scroll its contents vertically.
>   Scrolling can be done either per pixel or per item.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought I would find such a method in QAbstractScrollArea instead of QAbstractItemView...