# Scrolling QTableWidget smoothly with the mousewheel

Tags: c++, qt

As we can see in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719037/scrolling-qtablewidget-smoothly), it is possible to smooth the scrolling of a QTableWidget by using `view->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel)`, and this works perfectly when I drag the scroll bar and move it around.

What I'm trying to achieve here is when I turn the wheel of my mouse, the QTableWidget would scroll a few lines smoothly. I'm not looking for the [setSingleStep()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#singleStep-prop) function which would lead into a very very slow scrolling, but really to scroll my QTableWidget smoothly by a few lines like I scroll a web page in my web browser.

I think I may be able to do that by [making a custom WheelEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwheelevent.html#angleDelta) but it seems to be a lot of work for what I'm trying to achieve here. So I'd like to be sure I'm not trying to reinvent the (mouse) wheel.

Is there a simple solution (like the answer of the question I linked above) I have missed to achieve what I'm trying to do?

If not, would a custom WheelEvent be the right way to do that?

If not, what would be that right way?

I'm using Qt Creator 4.6 with Qt 5.11 if that matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its really not as bad as you would think to subclass QTableView. Here's my solution which includes some debug statements to show whats going on.  For `ScrollPerPixel` mode you may want to include a multiplication factor to `item` to have it scroll faster.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyTableClass : public QTableView //subclass standard QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* e)
    {
        QString result;
        int items = e->delta() > 0 ? (e->delta() + (e->DefaultDeltasPerStep - 1)) / e->DefaultDeltasPerStep :
                                     (e->delta() - (e->DefaultDeltasPerStep - 1)) / e->DefaultDeltasPerStep; //round away from zero

        qDebug() << QString("delta %1").arg(e->delta());
        qDebug() << QString("items %1").arg(items);
        if (e->orientation() == Qt::Vertical)
        {
            this->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(this->verticalScrollBar()->value()-items);
            if (items > 0)
            {
                result = "Mouse Wheel Event: UP";
            }
            else
            {
                result = "Mouse Wheel Event: DOWN";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(this->horizontalScrollBar()->value()-items);
            if (items > 0)
            {
                result = "Mouse Wheel Event: LEFT";
            }
            else
            {
                result = "Mouse Wheel Event: RIGHT";
            }
        }
        qDebug() << result;
    }
};

#include "main.moc" //assuming the file containing this code is named main.cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    QVBoxLayout* vbox = new QVBoxLayout();
    QTableView* tableView = new MyTableClass();

    vbox->addWidget(tableView);

    window.setLayout(vbox);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long time, and I didn't get the chance to work on this project again until now.